# How to assign current date to a custom field in a apex controller

Tags: query, date

```
transact.Transaction_Date__c=Date.Today();
```

Above is my code. Why am i getting yesterdays date?

Comment: Most likely due to timezone in org vs where you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.It was my TimeZone setting in Org.
I changed my "User" settings under setup -> User -> Time Zone.

Problem Solved

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause would be if the field `Transaction_Date__c` is a `DateTime` field, assigning a `Date` to it would set the hours/minutes/seconds to zero, and then the automatic [timezone](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/09/time-zones-software-development/) handling for your `User` would subtract (or add) hours and so move the `Date` part to the previous day. A quick fix for that would be:

```
transact.Transaction_Date__c=DateTime.Now();
```

but better to change the type of the field `Transaction_Date__c` to `Date` if that is what it represents.

If not the above, search for other code or configuration in your system that modifies the `Transaction_Date__c` field as the code you have posted looks correct.

Comment: Hai @keith C.. I tried using DateTime.Now( );  which gives me an error "DateTime variable doesn't exist"... so sick of being confused for this title  date problem... help me with this please

Comment: @Lokesh I don't understand that. If `Transaction_Date__c` is of type `Date` it won't help anyway. Post more of your code.

Comment: List<Transaction__c> bal = [Select Balance__c from Transaction__c ];
            System.debug('Balance' + bal);
            transact.Transaction_Date__c=Date.Today();
            if(!bal.isEmpty() && transact.Action__c == 'Deposit'){
                transact.Balance__c = bal[0].Balance__c + transact.Amount__c;
            }
            else if(!bal.isEmpty() && transact.Action__c == 'Withdrawal'){
                transact.Balance__c = bal[0].Balance__c - transact.Amount__c;
            }
            System.debug('Final Detail' + transact);
            insert transact;

Comment: @Lokesh Nothing much new in there. How are you presenting the data e.g. `apex:outputField`?

Comment: ....No i am not using in any where i am just calculating the current balance using the date...and i check the date through standard related list Home page